# Including the same headers in every class

Tags: c++, stl, header-files

I am including several STL headers such as list and vector in all my code files for my project.  I know for my own headers that I should use include guards, but what about for this scenario when they aren't defined by me?

Is it bad to include the same headers in every one of my files? Is there a performance penalty for each time it is included?

Comment: I am completely sure that you include *standard library* headers, not *STL* headers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no performance cost. The standard headers have their own include guards, and all include guards are optimized by the preprocessor so the file isn't actually reloaded each time.

Correctness and maintainability are always the first concern… how much compile time do you have to save to make up for work spent fixing things when you rearrange the files and get "undefined identifier" errors, or worse!

**EDIT:** There is no performance cost to multiply including the same standard headers from all your header files. There is some performance cost to including additional standard headers from a source file. The question is a bit ambiguous… but either way, the really expensive part of C++ compilation is usually template instantiation, not parsing the text.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule,
**You must only include the header files when your source file needs it.**

Include guards would prevent the same header file from being included in the same translation unit more than once and guard you against linking errors however, Ofcourse Standard library headers have their own.

However, note that If you include header files in source files which do not need them, then it just might increase your compilation & cause pollution of the namespace names.

Comment: Would you rather "get away" with having a symbol defined two different ways in two different files due to different header inclusion, or would you rather see an error? It shouldn't happen anyway without `using namespace`, which you shouldn't do, but even assuming that, the situation would be worthy of a red flag.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Why would one end up defining a symbol in two different ways in two different files? As long as they are standard library symbols and one doesn't intend to intentionally shoot oneself, that shouldn't occur at all & if it does happens it should be tracked down and corrected.

Comment: … more succinctly: namespace pollution isn't an effect of too many headers, it's an effect of defining things improperly in namespace scope.